# SQL find row value in other column of groups MAX() value - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have three tables containing movie, rating and reviewer data. A join of my data is shown below:

```
mysql root@localhost:foo> SELECT m.title, ra.stars, re.name
                       -> FROM Movie m
                       -> JOIN Rating ra ON m.mid = ra.mid
                       -> JOIN `Reviewer` re ON ra.rid = re.rid
                       -> ORDER BY m.title, ra.stars DESC;
+-------------------------+-------+------------------+
| title                   | stars | name             |
+-------------------------+-------+------------------+
| Avatar                  | 5     | James Cameron    |
| Avatar                  | 3     | Elizabeth Thomas |
| E.T.                    | 3     | Ashley White     |
| E.T.                    | 2     | Chris Jackson    |
| Gone with the Wind      | 4     | Sarah Martinez   |
| Gone with the Wind      | 3     | Mike Anderson    |
| Gone with the Wind      | 2     | Sarah Martinez   |
| Raiders of the Lost Ark | 4     | Brittany Harris  |
| Raiders of the Lost Ark | 4     | Chris Jackson    |
| Raiders of the Lost Ark | 2     | Brittany Harris  |
| Snow White              | 5     | Elizabeth Thomas |
| Snow White              | 4     | Daniel Lewis     |
| The Sound of Music      | 3     | Chris Jackson    |
| The Sound of Music      | 2     | Brittany Harris  |
+-------------------------+-------+------------------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is to group the table above by title and obtain the name of the reviewer that gave each movie the highest rating. Result should look like below.

```
+-------------------------+-------+------------------+
| title                   | stars | name             |
+-------------------------+-------+------------------+
| Avatar                  | 5     | James Cameron    |
| E.T.                    | 3     | Ashley White     |
| Gone with the Wind      | 4     | Sarah Martinez   |
| Raiders of the Lost Ark | 4     | Brittany Harris  |
| Raiders of the Lost Ark | 4     | Chris Jackson    |
| Snow White              | 5     | Elizabeth Thomas |
| The Sound of Music      | 3     | Chris Jackson    |
+-------------------------+-------+------------------+
```

I am somehow stuck on how to do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: I initially though that including another aggregate functions on stars column (`MAX(stars)`) was trivial, but I can't get it working. Any ideas how that might work?

Comment: Try my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** - from your result set:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM Your_Table A
JOIN(
    SELECT title,MAX(stars) stars
    FROM Your_Table
    GROUP BY title
    )B ON A.title = B.title AND A.stars = B.stars
```

**Second solution:** - From your Table

```
SELECT m.title, ra.stars, re.name
FROM Movie m
JOIN(
    SELECT R.* 
    FROM Rating R
    JOIN(
        SELECT mid
            ,MAX(stars) Stars
        FROM Rating
        GROUP BY mid
        )D ON R.mid = D.mid AND R.Stars = D.Stars
    )Ra ON m.mid = ra.mid
JOIN Reviewer re ON ra.rid = re.rid
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: I have tried to add the `SUM(stars)` per group to the result, but cannot get to work it out. Could you give me another hint?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.title, ra.stars, re.name
FROM Movie m
JOIN (SELECT mid,MAX(stars) AS stars FROM Rating GROUP BY mid) ra 
ON m.mid = ra.mid
JOIN Rating ra1
ON ra1.mid = ra.mid AND ra1.star=ra.star
JOIN Reviewer re 
ON ra1.rid = re.rid
ORDER BY m.title, ra.stars DESC;
```

Comment: You got a little typo though, it should read `ra1.stars = ra.stars` on line 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT m.title, ra.stars, re.name
       FROM Movie m
      JOIN Rating ra ON m.mid = ra.mid
      JOIN Reviewer re ON ra.rid = re.rid
      JOIN 
 (SELECT m.title, max(ra.stars) as stars
       FROM Movie m
      JOIN Rating ra ON m.mid = ra.mid
      GROUP BY m.title) c
ON c.title=m.title AND ra.stars=c.stars
      ORDER BY m.title, ra.stars DESC
```

Comment: Thank you lucumt!

Answer (score 1):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
SELECT m.title, ra.stars, re.name
FROM Movie m
JOIN Rating ra ON m.mid = ra.mid
JOIN Reviewer re ON ra.rid = re.rid
WHERE ra.stars = ( SELECT MAX(ra1.stars) FROM Movie m1 JOIN Rating ra1 on m1.mid = ra1.mid WHERE m1.title = m.title) 
ORDER BY m.title, ra.stars DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick reply!